# Checking LAMP Installation in Linux

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, mysql, lamp

I had installed PHP, MYSQL and APACHE in linux server, How can I check the installation and running status of Apache, MYSQL, PHP are correct in Linux server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Apache

Go to `http://localhost:80` on your web browser. A page saying your Apache server is running properly should show up.

[image: sample screenshot]

If this isn't working, confirm your apache service is running and restart it if necessary by running `service apache2 restart`.

Files placed in `/var/www/html` should be served by the Apache server.

## PHP

Place a php file in `/var/www/html` and navigate to it `http://localhost/yourFile.php` to check if it runs correctly. Apache serves php pages so if Apache is running fine then PHP should be as well.

Example steps

```
cd /var/www/html
vim helloWorld.php
```

At this point, go into insert mode (press i), key in `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, and then `:wq!` to save and quit. Then go to `http://localhost/helloWorld.php` to confirm the output of `phpinfo()` shows up.

## mySQL

You can simply key in `mysql -u root -p` to login and set a password, then key in mySQL commands. Alternatively, for a GUI, consider installing `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: then how to check the php and my sql installations

Comment: edited my answer